# Halo in OpenLayers (Line, Vector)

Tags: openlayers, vector

How to make a halo around the line of one pixel using OpenLayers?

For example, the line (vector) has  a blue color and its frame (one pixel) has a black color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Use `strokeWidth : 1` and `strokeColor: '#000000'` on the vector's style</strike>

Actually, after testing what I said, turns out it's not that simple.

Looks like lines don't use the `fill` property at all and instead only use `stroke`.

So the only way I was able to do it was by cloning the feature and modifying the style. So you have 2 features.

<strike>Here's the DEMO</strike>
[Demo LINK UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/AG2xB/1/)

[image]

Comment: In demo i see 2 lines: black and white, without halo. I have an idea: draw two times the same line, only the second line will be slightly thicker than the first and will have a different color.

Comment: For fixing proposed example use the same geometry definition for both lines.

Comment: Sorry, I put in the wrong DEMO link. Just updated it which should reflect what both of you (dedoki and drnextgis) are saying.

Comment: In terms of web map cartography, this has generally been the route used by the most popular engines. I remember using this technique when styling maps in Tilemill which uses Carto.